# How do you create a Journal using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I was wondering how do you create a journal using a batch file?

I want to be able to save my journal entries and create a date. I would like to save it using a .log file if it is possible. I have to code for the journal itself below.

```
:JOU
ECHO ====Journal====
echo.
ECHO Please add an entry, Joshua.
@pause >nul
echo.
ECHO ====Entries====
echo.
set /p datej1="Date: "
set /p entriesj1="Entries: "
cls
ECHO 1. Date: %datej1% Entries: %entriesj1%
echo.
set /p datej2="Date: "
set /p entriesj2="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 2. Date: %datej2% Entries: %entriesj2%
echo.
set /p datej3="Date: "
set /p entriesj3="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 3. Date: %datej3% Entries: %entriesj3%
echo.
set /p datej4="Date: "
set /p entriesj4="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 4. Date: %datej4% Entries: %entriesj4%
echo.
set /p datej5="Date: "
set /p entriesj5="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 5. Date: %datej5% Entries: %entriesj5%
echo.
set /p datej6="Date: "
set /p entriesj6="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 6. Date: %datej6% Entries: %entriesj6%
echo.
set /p datej7="Date: "
set /p entriesj7="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 7. Date: %datej7% Entries: %entriesj7%
echo.
set /p datej8="Date: "
set /p entriesj8="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 8. Date: %datej8% Entries: %entriesj8%
echo.
set /p datej9="Date: "
set /p entriesj9="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 9. Date: %datej9% Entries: %entriesj9%
echo.
set /p datej10="Date: "
set /p entriesj10="Entries: "
echo.
ECHO 10. Date: %datej10% Entries: %entriesj10%
echo.
ECHO Press any key to exit Journal.
@pause >nul
cls
```

Comment: you need to [redirect](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) your `ECHO`s to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, it will save everything you type into cmd to the desktop as Logs.log (You cant delete lines with this however so make sure you dont make any mistakes in your typing!)

```
@echo off
goto :EditText

:EditText
set /p TextInput= 
echo %TextInput% >> %systemdrive%/Users/%username%/Desktop/Logs.log
goto :EditText
```

If you want the date and time to be added to the journal entry, use this code instead:

```
@echo off
set A=%systemdrive%/Users/%username%/Desktop/Logs.log
goto :EditText
:EditText
set /p TextInput= 
echo. >> %A%
echo %time% on %date%: >> %A%
echo %TextInput% >> %A%
goto :EditText
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Your very welcome. Also if you want to overwrite a file use only one ">"

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: I've made some edits and I have added a version that adds the Date and Time to the entry and adds an empty line inbetween entries.

Comment: Thanks. It helps a lot to have date & time in it.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a useful alternative below.

```
:Code
@ECHO OFF
START notepad "%userprofile%\Desktop\Diary.txt"
END
```

create the file `Diary.txt` on your desktop and write .LOG in it. Close it then run `:Code` in a .bat file.
It saves the date and time as well as what you type to `Diary.txt`

Comment: This is not was requested. The user requested a notepad *program* made *inside* of a batch file, not a notepad.exe starter. Besides, if they want the date and time to be written, they can just do the 2nd code I have offered in my answer.

Comment: @J03L"create a journal using a batch file" doesn't have to mean re-inventing the wheel. Considering that there are millions of journal programs I just gave him a Useful "alternative" Meaning something that will create the same end result without having to get to technical with the raw batch code. Furthermore the DOS language was not intended to be used for developing journals.It leans more on the side of automation. Lastly I recommended an easy method because the user is quite new and most certainly has limited knowledge on MS DOS.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest answer to it:**

1. open your notepad
2. write following in it: .LOG
3. save this file with .txt extension. For ex:  Diary.txt
4. now open this file.

Now you can use this as your diary.
When you open it will automatically write the date and save your text every time.